# ES6 Is there any way to assign the same value for two and more object properties using curly braces definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to assign the same **anonymous** arrow function to two different properties of the same object, which is defined *with curly braces*. E.g. now I have:

```
let testObject = {a: (a) => a+1, b: (a) => a+1};
```

And I want something like (pseudo-code):

```
let testObject = {a: b: (a) => a+1};
```

I actually know how to solve that problem (that is not a problem). But if there could be some way to assign the same *intermediate* (neither the variables, nor the primitives) values to two or more object properties like in a pseudo-code above, that would be very useful, isn't it?

Comment: You can do this: `testObject.a = testObject.b = (x) => x+1;` Not exactly the solution you're looking for though, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG , I need an object to be completely declared with **curly braces**.

Comment: best you probably can do is a function that returns the object and passing in the function to it.... I do not think you are going to get anything better.  I am wondering what the real problem is you are trying to "solve"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let testObject = (fn => ({a: fn, b: fn}))(a => a+1);
```

Comment: Technically, this is the solution. But I have lots of such assignments in object (I mean, lots of functions, and properties). A complete object has a size up to 1k lines of code, so, I think this is not very convenient to have a list of all the huge functions in the very end of an object. But the solution is good, thank you!

Comment: @impulsgraw Is it a huge list of function, or just a list of huge functions? Also, why do you have so many duplicated methods?

Comment: @Bergi, huge list of fat functions. There are so much duplicated properties because of using the vendor interface, so, it was declared not by me, I can't change anything in that third-party library.

Comment: Sounds like want to write your implementation, and then a separate [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the ugly vendor interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in the way you describe.

---

You could assign the function to a variable, but then it's not anonymous anymore:

```
const myFunc = a => a + 1;
const testObject = {a: myFunc, b: myFunc};
```

Comment: Logically you are right. But there is actually the one very huge function and it should be assigned to two object properties (exactly like in my example above). The main problem is that is should be used only in context of that object, so, imagine if you will need to do something like that a couple times in a row, so, you will have a dump of one-time-used unnecessary variables, which were defined only for one assignment of the same value to two different object properties...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't worry about that until you have to. It improves the maintainability of your code, since your function actually has a name now that tells the developer what it does. If you actually run into performance issues, you can analyze where the problem lies and think about solutions, but I'd strongly suspect that your bottlenecks will be somewhere else in practice. Do not sacrifice maintainability for premature optimization.

Comment: Ok, then, your answer misconcepts the question. I was asking exactly about the anonymous function assignment. There is actually not the only reason why I am asking exactly what I am asking. I have omitted lots of details of the code and the project I am speaking about generally to make the question more readable and to simplify everything. There is no need for you or everyone there to read a very large code listing to answer the same question if it can be truncated.